# Resizing a custom XYChart in an FXML Tab Pane

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

This question related to Java-FX and its charting capabilities and resizing.

My problem is that I wanted to create a custom candlestick chart and I managed to get that done by going through the Ensemble application source code which was quite helpful.

The code for generating the candlestick is here:

http://javafx-ui-hxzon.googlecode.com/svn-history/r13/trunk/ChartsSampler/chartssampler/CandleStickChart.java

However, when I run my application, I seem to be stuck with a chart size that is fixed and does not resize according to my Tab Pane (the parent) resizing in my GUI. I've gone through the code, fiddled with it, changed the value of the minWidth and minHeight to USE_PREF_WIDTH AND USE_COMPUTE_WIDTH both but I cannot get it to fit to the parent Tab pane.

What am I missing?

I call AdvCandleStickChartSample in my controller as follows:

```
AdvCandleStickChartSample adv=new AdvCandleStickChartSample();
candleTab.setContent(adv);//candleTab has been predefined in an FXML file
```

My guess is I need to resize based on an event-handler? Am I correct in assuming this? Or am I not overriding a specific method that handles the resizing? When I create a dummy linechart and fill it with data and "run" it, it resizes fine along with the window.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind.

I found the answer. I simply had to override the layoutChildren() method by implementing the Pane superclass.

In the Ensemble application they accomplish this by implementing a "Sample" class which overrides the Pane super-class's layoutChildren() method